# specific permissions to a table based on user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have a table which contains two columns. One is called `Directory`, the other `UserName`.

To explain my problem I think a simple example is easier.

So this table has 3 users. In the `UserName` column, only the 3 users, usernames can be entered plus one other entry called `Default`.

```
Directory     UserName
C:\Blah       Bob
C:\BlaF       Brad
C:\BlaK       Dave
C:\BlaPP      Default
C:\Anoth      Default
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible to allow only two of the users to be able to insert, delete records with the username `Default` and the other user to be able to only select the records with `Default`.

Is this possible?

**Update**

After doing some reading is it not possible to do this using an Instead of trigger? So in my understanding this trigger will fire before an insert, update or delete query is executed. So I was thinking in the trigger if could check the host pc (users on my team will only be using their computer) to see who it is trying to insert, update or delete and if its a user who doesn't have permission to edit the default list then exit the trigger and don't update the table. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is not possible with direct access to the table.   But it can be managed with views and stored procedures.

Comment: It is possible with triggers as well.

Comment: @LeBarton - Not the `SELECT` requirement.

Comment: @TabAlleman how could this be managed with views and stored procedures? I'm very much a novice with sql server

Comment: Do you mean that Bob,Brad and Dave should all be able to insert rows with their own name but only Bob and Brad should be able to insert rows with `default`?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes that is basically what I am after if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving users direct access to the table, give the first two users access to a stored procedure that inserts to the table, and only inserts "Default" for the username.

Give the third user access to a view (or stored procedure) that only selects records where username="Default".